# automatically send request to server in phonegap

Tags: android, web-services, cordova

i am trying to develop an application in which i need to send some data to the server,but if the device is not connected to net or net connectivity is not there then it should store the data in the local storage and send it to server once the device gets net access, automatically..
I am able to store it in the local storage but beyond that i am not sure how to begin,please guide me,is it possible to send the data after net connects??while surfing for this issue i stumbled on one more tool "adobe LiveCycle" can anyone throw some light on it??

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a service and call that service through javaScript and put a timer or so to automatically post your data to server.

Comment: can you please tell me how to develope / create service that service through javaScript and put a timer or so to automatically post your data to server? please guide me, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's PhoneGap function to check the connection. Then you just need to call it from time to time and store the data if there's no internet connection or send your request any other case.

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```